# Twitter4J Glassfish v3

Tags: jsp, twitter, glassfish, twitter4j

im trying to make web application that connects to twitter.
Im trying to get information from public time line twitter and I use twitter4j library.

When doing the java code to retrieve the information it is fine and works. however when i call the method to jsp it shows this.

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/log/Logger;
        at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:125)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
...
```

anyone can help me why i get this error? im googling it but seems not find the correct solution :(. I see no error in my project.

What i  did before twitter4j is added:
- adding twitter4j library to web application-> error need logger something and i add logger library
- then after that there is an error about org.apache.avalon and after i add the library it shows this message.

SERVER : GLASSFISH V3
IDE : NETBEANS 6.9.1
JAVA EE 6

Thank you :D

already include org.apache.log.logger from andyb answer but it will cause another error

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdmk/comm/CommunicatorServer
        at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:125)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
```

i've already added org.apache.log.logger from this jar http://www.findjar.com/jar/logkit/logkit/2.0/logkit-2.0.jar.html

is that the correct one?

im getting more error when i added jar, actually what is the correct one to add twitter4j to glassfish v3?
do i need to add that POM.xml that andyb gave?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `WeldDeployer` is trying to log something at line 167 but the logging library it is dependant on is missing. The error you are seeing - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` - is the Java runtime telling you it is missing a class.

<strike>The missing class is called `org.apache.log.Logger`. You need to find the .jar that contains this class and add that as a dependency of your project.</strike> ← Don't do this - `org.apache.log.logger` has been retired!

I guess you are not using Maven, otherwise I would hope that the dependancies would be added automatically. However if you check the [Twitter4j POM file](http://twitter4j.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/2.2.1/twitter4j-core-2.2.1.pom) there are 4 dependancies: `junit`, `slf4j-api`, `commons-logging-api` and `log4j`.

**Edit:** I was not sure if you were using Maven to build your project. If you are, then how did you add twitter4j to your project? Did you add the following to you **project** POM? If so, then the dependencies should have been downloaded automatically by Maven. The [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) site has instructions on how to add the library to a POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, however i still got another error after i find org.apache.log.logger

Comment: Which logging library did you add? It looks like you've added a logging library that is old. Apache Avalon was superseded by Excalibur (and some other projects) years ago. Even Excalibur is now closed! Have you tried adding log4j? It is not clear from your question which logging library you added.

Comment: oops i've not finished edit my comment. ^^ sorry. i've updated the status in my question above. im using org.apache.log4j_1.2.13.v200806030600.jar

Comment: commons-io-1.4.jar
junit 4.5 - junit-4.5 jar
twitter-4j-core-2.2.1-sources.jar
org.apache.commons.loggin_1.04v20080605-1930.jar
org.apache.log4j_1.2.13.v20080603600.jar
avalon.jar
logkit-2.0 jar
those are libraries that i've added so far.

Comment: `org.apache.log.logger` from [here](http://www.findjar.com/jar/logkit/logkit/2.0/logkit-2.0.jar.html) is **very** old. I would expect that `WeldDeployer` in Glassfish is log4j compatible. Can you try removing the `avalon.jar` and `logkit2.0.jar` (these are both old) and just use the 4 libraries from the `<dependencies>` section in the twitter4j POM linked in my answer above?

Comment: what should i do with the POM file? do i just need to copy paste it to my existing pom file? or i need to added one by one the library again? and where should i put the inside of pom file? to my glassfish folder or my project? sorry for asking a lot of questions :(. im still newbie about this thing.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the correct dependency to add in your POM.

Comment: im using glassfishv3, is that maven? i don't know what maven is :( i just add twitter4j jar file by right clicking and add jar. and code dependency of the pom, where should i put it? in POM.xml of glassfish v3 folder or my project folder? because when i searched there are pom.xml in glassfish folder and project folder

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Glassfish, so don't know how to answer that. Glassfish is not Maven though. Maven is a tool for building and managing a Java-based project. It sounds like you have added the `twitter4j.jar` file without it's dependencies. Please can you try adding the `<dependency>` block in my answer above to the `pom.xml` in your project folder.

Comment: hmmm actualy the pom.xml is not in my project. the pom.xml is inside twitter4j 2.2.1.zip however i only add library from that zip is twitter4j2.2.1-core.jar which does not have pom.xml. so where should i put the POM.xml and where i put the block of dependencies? just add to the bottom of the root node? or still inside the root node?

Comment: Oh, so you **are not** using Maven! Do not change the twitter4j POM. You can ignore all the POM advice above now since you are not using Maven. The problem is about missing dependencies for twitter4j. Those dependencies are [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html), [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi) and [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html). I suggest you manually download those libraries and add them to your Glassfish project.